# Reference Value Copy

Tags: java, reference, linked-list, copy, stack

im implementing a Stack dynamically in JAVA, and i've come to this question. the thing is, my code works and i dont know why. so here is my part of the code that i dont understand:

```
  Node<E> newNode = new Node(elem,top);
  newNode=top;
  size++;
```

so, the 2nd argument of my newNode is the object right next to it , wich is top in this case.
then i say that my newNode=top; so, by my logic , newNode is next to newNode because i said in the instruction after that newNode = top; what am i missing here? i know its a dumb question :( the thing is, it works and i've seen some similar implementations i just dont understand why it works.

EDIT: ill post my whole code:

Class node:

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

}
```

//ENDS HERE

interface stack:

```
public interface Stack<E>  {

    //numero de elementos presentes na pilha 
    public int size( ); 
    //nao contem elementos?
    public boolean isEmpty( ); 
    //devolve proximo objecto a sair, sem remover
    public E peek( )    
        throws EmptyStackException; 

    //empilha novo elemento
    public void push(E o)   
        throws FullStackException;
    //desempilha proximo elemento                                                                                     
    public E pop()          
        throws EmptyStackException;     
}
```

//INTERFACE ENDS HERE

Class StackDynamic

```
public class StackDynamic<E> implements Stack<E>{


    private int size;
    private Node<E> top;
    private int maxCapacity;


    public StackDynamic(int capacity)
    {
      this.maxCapacity=capacity;
      this.size=0;
      this.top=null;
    }

    public StackDynamic()
    {
      this(-1);

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
}

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
       return (this.size == 0);

    }

    @Override
    public E peek() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException("A pilha está vazia.");
        }
        return top.getElement();

    }

    @Override
    public void push(E elem) throws FullStackException {
    if(size==maxCapacity){
        throw new FullStackException("Está cheio");
    }
    **Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(elem, top);


    top=newNode;
    size++;**  //error here
    }

    @Override
    public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException("A pilha está vazia.");
        }

         E elemRemoved = top.getElement();
         top = top.getNext();
         size--;
         return elemRemoved;




    }
```

//CLASS ENDS HERE

now the newNode=top; commands dont make a lot of sense to me :S

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up the order in the second statement? I'd expect it to be `top = newNode;`.

Comment: I guess we need some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it "works" because

- the code is not what you say it is (my first though but I dismissed it)
- code elsewhere hides the bugs
- you haven't tested the code properly.

I suspect if you delete the `newNode=top;` line it will still "work"

Comment: @PedroCosta I can't find the line you are asking about as the code you quote is correct.  Can you highlight the incorrect line for me?

Comment: done mate :D its on method Push of class stack dynamic , and i put the code on BOLD.

Comment: @PedroCosta I still cannot see `newNode=top;`, I can only see `top=newNode;`

Comment: yea thats it , top=newNode. if i say top=newNode, the new node is pointing to itself, no ? =S

Comment: @PedroCosta No. The `top` is a node which points to the old value of `top` I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will be able to see what is happening.

Comment: @PedroCosta Which is why it was such a mystery as to why it worked anyway. ;)